# Unable to open .dmp file with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, crash-dumps

I have some files in a Minidump folder that I would like to look at, because I am trying to track down the cause of some blue screens I occasionally get. My hard drive configuration seems to randomly change from RAID to AHCI once in awhile too, and I am hoping these files may give me some clue as to what is going on. I have Visual Studio 2012, but when I try to open the file I get:

`Debugging older format crashdumps is not supported`

What does this mean, and is there some kind of plug-in I can get for VS or something that will allow me to open these files? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

BSODs write kernel dumps, which [Visual Studio is not capable of processing](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768951/visual-studio-2012-cant-open-mini-dumps-created-by-windows-7).

Consider trying WinDbg.

Comment: The link in this post is now completely broken. It doesn't redirect to anything useful, and there are no archived copies of its content on Wayback or archive.is.

Comment: It looks like more recent versions of VS can debug kernel dumps, though. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2022 : *"To debug kernel-mode dump files or use the SOS.dll debugging extension in Visual Studio, download the debugging tools for Windows in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK)."*
Though it also states *"Visual Studio can't debug dump files saved in the older, full user-mode dump format. A full user-mode dump is not the same as a dump with heap."*